# Spring Security User

Tags: spring-security

What is best practise in Spring when creating a new user with custom attributes...to extend org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User or to create the User in the UserDetailsService (this is the approach taken in the IceFaces tutorial).

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    AppUser user = userDAO.findUser(username);
    if (user == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found: " + username);
    else {
        return makeUser(user);
    }
}

private User makeUser(AppUser user) {
    return new User(user.getLogin(), user
            .getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
            makeGrantedAuthorities(user));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user permissions fit into the context of the Spring Security User class then simply writing your own `UserDetails` service is fine.  But if your Users have other attributes that are not encapsulated in the available fields in the default `User`class then you will need to do both.  There's not really a "best practice" - both are fine options it really depends on your use case.